# filling empty space by the elements

Tags: html, css, grid

I have module adding image, all image is scaling to 25% width and have float:left. When I add rectangular image in middle there is empty space. This is rectangle (2) in my image, I want to square (5) go to empty space.

Could you give me any tips how I can do this?

[image: grid image]

Comment: If you add a <div> (or any element you're using) after the element nr. 4 and make it float right for 25%, it might do the trick. Im not sure though.
Maybe you could post a JSFiddle of your html/css applying to this image, your chances of someone solving this will be higher if you do so.

Comment: Here is:[link](http://jsfiddle.net/dLnwfr56)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a wrapper div and make it float completely left for the width you want the elements inside it to be, you can fill it up.

```css
.small {
  width:25%; 
  float:left; 
  height:50px; 
  background:#f0f;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 1px #fff, 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  margin-bottom:10px;
  }
  .inWrapper{
float:none;
width:100%
  }
  
.height {height:110px}
.long {width:50%}
.smallwrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  width:25%
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
<div class="smallwrapper">
<div class="small inWrapper">
1
</div>
<div class="small inWrapper">
NEW
</div>
</div>
<div class="small height">
2
</div>
<div class="small">
3
</div>
<div class="small">
4
</div>
<div class="small">
5
</div>
<div class="small">
6
</div>
<div class="small long">
7
</div>
<div class="small long">
8
</div>
<div class="small">
9
</div>
</div>
```

Note: this looks good because you have defined your height, making the smaller ones exactly twice as high (with margin) as the bigger one.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not solution for me, because I cant add conteiner as in your example. I have module uploading image in conteiner, their width and height is 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%, so it depends on uploading image resolutions. Every uploadded image creating conteiner `<div class=""></div>` so I cant put there custom conteiner smallwrapper. I also tried masonry css http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/JFpeg but it's also not worked as I expected.